# Out of bounds error UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I got this code set up for my app that has a notepad-similar function:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {
        // Set ignoreDefaultsChanged to YES so that the defaultsChanged method won't interfere with the deletion of a summary
        ignoreDefaultsChanged = YES;

        // OUT OF BOUNDS ERROR
        [_objects removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        // Delete the associated information
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", _objects[indexPath.row], @"-summary"]];

        // Save the new list of combined summaries
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_objects forKey:@"prepareKey"];
    } 
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) 
    {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}

- (void)defaultsChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if (ignoreDefaultsChanged == YES) 
    {
        // Do nothing
    } 
    else if (ignoreDefaultsChanged == NO)
    {
        // Setup savingKey
        savingKey = @"prepareKey";

        // Load the items from NSUserDefaults
        _objects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:savingKey]];

        // Reload the tableView
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    // Register a class or nib file using registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier
    // o registerClass:forCellReuiseIdentifier: method before calling this method
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    // Setup savingKey
    savingKey = @"prepareKey";

    // Load the items from NSUserDefaults
    _objects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:savingKey]];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(defaultsChanged:) name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}
```

**If I now try to delete the bottom-most cell, the app crashes with this message:**

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 5]'
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: The error makes no sense. 2 is not beyond the bounds of 0..5. Are you sure that is the actual error message?

Comment: Suspect it is similar to this ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016200/how-can-i-make-deleterowsatindexpaths-work-with-generictableviewcontroller`

Comment: Ohh, sorry - i edited those values to make the question clearer. I deleted the top most values and when I copied to to SO it was 0 and 1/2. An error I got was that index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4] @rmaddy

Comment: What do you think? @rmaddy