# When I am trying to delete row from table the application crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

some times I can delete the first record of the table but then after I can't delete the other row.

I declare an array

```
@implementation TableViewController{
NSMutableArray *tableData;
}
```

view did load method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     tableData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", @"Full Breakfast", @"Hamburger", @"Ham and Egg Sandwich", @"Creme Brelee", @"White Chocolate Donut", @"Starbucks Coffee", @"Vegetable Curry", @"Instant Noodle with Egg", @"Noodle with BBQ Pork", @"Japanese Noodle with Pork", @"Green Tea", @"Thai Shrimp Cake", @"Angry Birds Cake", @"Ham and Cheese Panini", nil];
}
```

set the label for row

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return [tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView   cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil){
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    cell.nameLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    
    return cell;
}
```

when I swipe the delete button appeared.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    //remove the row from data model
    [tableData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView reloadData];
}

@end
```

Comment: And what's the error message?

Comment: There is no error. when I try to delete the record, the application crash and log shows only (11db) nothing else

Comment: There is always an error message.

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/model-view-controller-delete-table-row-from-uitableview/ In this u will get entire code..It is working fine..for me..
Same code is there in this sample also

Comment: @Vidhyanand900, not entirely, the difference between the OP and the tutorial is how he reloads his custom cell. In the tutorial it's: `cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];`, but the OP loads it from a nib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    //remove the row from data model
    [tableData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That will cause a different error without solving the original error.

Comment: I wouldn't have posted an answer if i didn't try it first.

Comment: You must replicate the problem first if you want to see if your answer will solve it. This answer won't solve it, meaning you did not replicate the problem, ergo this answer does not actually answer the question. It also helps to tell the OP why it crashed, not just giving him the code so he can copy paste it.

Comment: See this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016200/how-can-i-make-deleterowsatindexpaths-work-with-generictableviewcontroller) for why the code presented in this answer will fail.