# How to delete a specific row?

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, uitableview, nsindexpath

Hi I am working with the chat app every thing is working fine.Now I need to delete a message.For that i am using long Gesture on tableview.But My Tableview is configured like sections are Dates and messages are Rows.Now when Long Tap on row it is showing Row number not respect to Sections.So I am using below Code it showing the currect index path.Then I am deleting That message in sqlite.But getting error like index Beyond the Exception

```
 CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView];

 NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView  indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];

 id<SOMessage> message = self.conversation[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];

 int index = (int)[[self messages] indexOfObject:message];

 if (indexPath == nil) {

     NSLog(@"long press on table view but not on a row");

 } else if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

      NSLog(@"long press on table view at row %d", index);
}
```

in the above code, index is my indexapth value for deleting a row.and how i am deleting row in tableview is

```
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

below is my error log

```
invalid number of rows in section 1.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (10) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (10), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

Comment: Cannot really understand what you want. It seems that you set the datasource for the tableView, so that you either reload the table, or use `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` after you remove the message from your datasource.

Comment: I am working with the chatting screen for that i am using somessaging Third party library. i need to delete a message for that using above code for getting index path it is showing currect index only  but getting error like beyond the bound. because it is returning section rows in numberof rows. so may be i am missing some thing at indexpath

Comment: Still not clear what's the problem. Please update your question with error message and the exact code you were trying.

Comment: please check updated one

Comment: This might help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016200/how-can-i-make-deleterowsatindexpaths-work-with-generictableviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Not getting you question... you are doing every thing right, if you are able to delete row in sqlite with this then you can even in UITableView.
To delete row directly from table view just add following in your code:

```
else if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

      [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

}
```

I really didn't get your question but hope this may help :)