# tableview remove last row in section

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview

I've done many hours researching in stackoverflow/google and did studied several posts regards to similar problems. Yet none of them addressed the particular problem I have.

In a nutshell, I have a NSMutableArray of NSMutableDictionay(-ies). Each dictionary contains a NSMutableArray. When I delete the last item in the array, I'd like to remove the dictionary as well.  In tableview words, I would like to delete the section when deleting the last row in that section.

I am sure the data source is consistent.

this post here: [UITableView: deleting sections with animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061071/uitableview-deleting-sections-with-animation/1265050#1265050) suggests to remove the section directly if the row to be removed is the last row.

**This works fine if the section is the last section in my root array.**

The bug I found is that, if the section **is not the last section**, the section after it will take its place. When the system is drawing the deletion animation, it would throw an `NSInternalInconsistencyException`.

Say, I have section 0 and section 1, both with one row. When I remove indexPath (0,0), I detect section 0 should go instead because it has only one row, then I remove section 0 in `commitEditingStyle`

**The exception is thrown because user deleted Row 0 in Section 0, so the resulting number of rows in Section 0 should change from 1 to 0. However, after the removal, old Section 1 becomes Section 0 now, and it will return number of rows in Section 0 is 1.**

Is there any suggestions here? Or am I missing something very simple?

My code in commitEditingSytle:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[... remove the  item from array of this dictionary...]
// if last row in section, remove the section
NSNumber *section = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger: indexPath.section];
if ([[FoodTypes subtypes:section] count] == 0) 
{
    [...remove the dictionary from root array...]

    [tableView deleteSections: [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex: indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:YES];
}
else 
{
    // otherwise, remove the row only
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: Leo did you find an solution for this issue, where you preserve an deletion animation? Or you satyed with reloadData approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to delete an dictionary from your array which is its object as subscripted  variable then you need this single line.

```
[yourObject removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
```

and then reload the table by this line

```
[yourTable reloadData];
```

now since your table depends on this data source then it automatically remove from the table.

Comment: in the else statement, I think @leo would need to remove that row object from the array as well

Comment: This is a valid trick that saves a lot of programming efforts but loses the benefit of removing animation. Is there a way to keep the animation?

Comment: @leo In case of reload Data you can't animate the action.

Comment: @tegbanis you are right, i think there is no if and else, same thing happens.