# Hide or remove section from uitableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview

i am implementing a grouped table view in my application, where user can select row from different section of table.

i want to hide(remove) particular section(including header) depending upon selection of row of first section.

i.e.

first sections header is "Do you own car?", answer would be YES or NO in row selection.
if user selects NO, second and third section from grouped table should hide(remove).

for radio selection in grouped table, i implement [this](http://walkingsmarts.com/creating-radio-button-and-checkbox-lists-using-uitableview/)

i also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061071/uitableview-deleting-sections-with-animation) but does not full fill what i need.

Please help.

**Edit**

TableViewDelegates

myArray is my datasource.
myArrayAnswerCount contains count of number of row per section

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [myArray count];
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    for (int i = 0; i<[myArray count]; i++) {
        if (section==i) {
            return [[myArray objectAtIndex:i] title];
        }
    }
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    for (int i = 0; i<[myArray count]; i++) {
        if (section==i) {
            return [[myArrayAnswerCount objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
        }
    }
}
```

this is code for how i removes section from table,
myIndexPath is NSIndexPath variable which is pointing to section which is currently selected.

```
[table beginUpdates];
[myArray removeObjectAtIndex:myIndexPath.section];
[table deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:myIndexPath.section] withRowAnimation:YES];
[table endUpdates];
```

Comment: take a look here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved my question.

```
[table beginUpdates];
[myArray removeObjectAtIndex:myIndexPath.section];
[table deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:myIndexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
[table endUpdates];
```

The issue in "invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (3)" error was i forgot to remove object from myArrayAnswerCount array too.

so finally following code

```
[table beginUpdates];
[myArray removeObjectAtIndex:myIndexPath.section];
[myArrayAnswerCount removeObjectAtIndex:myIndexPath.section]; //this is what i forgot.
[table deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:myIndexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
[table endUpdates];
```

thanks.

Comment: Is myArrayAnswerCount the value of [myArray count] or some other value.If I give [[myArray Count] removeObjectAtIndex:],it is throwing a warning "method removeObjectAtIndex" not found,please help me,thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Eshwar Chaitanya: myArrayAnswerCount contains number of row per section in table. It is obvious a mutable array.

Comment: I have only 1 row per section and the number of sections vary when ever I add a reminder in add reminder page,please suggest me accordingly,thanks in advance :)

Comment: What I mean is when I press edit,I am able to press the - sign and delete the cell,but again when I navigate back and enter the view where we perform edit and delete actions,the deleted cell is still available,how to make a section delete permanently,Thanks :)

Comment: @EshwarChaitanya: myArrayAnswerCount is just a mutable array which contains row count for each section in table (it would be an int count, in  your case its value might be 1 for each section). including that you also need to remove value from data source (you might have use an mutable array for that). first check that. also debug your code accordingly.

Comment: ,Hi If you don't mind and when ever you find free time,please go through this link once,please 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708543/get-selected-value-of-a-picker-view-that-is-present-in-different-view-and-use-th

Thanks for everything and Happy new year :)

Answer (score 0):

You could check in your `UITableViewDataSource` like:

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)aTableView{
             if(YOUR_INSTANCE_BOOL_VAR==NO){
                   return 1;
             }else{
                   return 3;
             }
 }
```

After the user select NO turn your YOUR_INSTANCE_BOOL_VAR to NO, then recall `[tableView reloadData]`;
Obviously you also have to manipulate `numberOfRowsInSection` to trigger how many rows you want after the user select NO.

Another way is to call: `- (void)deleteSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;`

You can get rows indexPaths with:

```
+ (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForRow:(NSUInteger)row inSection:(NSUInteger)section;
```

Comment: @Mat : Hi, i have choose to use - (void)deleteSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation; method, now how can i update my data(i mean NSMutableArray), that are loaded in grouped table, after successful removel of particular section from group?

Comment: I don't know what type of objects you have in your NSMutableArray and in what order, but with NSMutableArray you can add/remove/replace any objects by accessing the index.

Comment: @Mat : hi, i got some error "invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (3)" while deleting section 0. is it mandatory that section 1 must have equal numbers of row to section 0 while deleting section?

Comment: This is a classic problem, probably because reloadData is called before you modify the dataSource, but if you edit your question and post your tableviewdelegate and tableviewdatasource callbacks maybe  we can better understand where is the problem.

Comment: @Mat : Hi, i solved issue, actually i forget to remove object from myArrayAnswerCount. that's why it was showing me such error. thanks for help..

Answer (score 0):

If you're not trying to actually remove the section or row, but just hide it. You can use:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView reloadSections:[NSindexSet indexSetWithIndex:(indexOfSection)] withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimationOfChoice)]; //hide section
```

OR

```
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimationOfChoice)]; //hide rows
[tableView endUpdates];
```

If you read the documentation, it says that these behave similarly to the deleting/inserting methods, however they're not actually removed so there's no need to have to delete/insert. You can call that method two hide or unhide.