# Get selected value of a picker view that is present in different view and use the string in some other view

Tags: iphone, uipickerview, selectedindex

I have a picker view in a view controller page,say view controller1.Now I have a requirement of accessing the selected string value from that picker view in another view controller say view controller 2.

This is because,I have a table view which displays the saved data corresponding to 4 groups i.e. my application is reminder application which user saves the reminder,that is visible in view reminder page.The reminders are saved by the user in respective groups,say friends,family,office etc... So I have earlier retrieved in a bad programming context,i.e.

I took 4 view controllers for displaying reminders corresponding to 4 groups i.e. say friendsViewController for displaying reminders corresponding to friends using the query

```
NSString *getQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM reminders WHERE Grp = 'Friends' GROUP BY Name,Event,Date"];
```

Like wise for group family,office and acquaintances.Hence for shifting the context of bad programming to a good programming habit,I have got an idea of using the query:

```
NSString *getQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM reminders WHERE Grp = '%@' GROUP BY Name,Event,Date",**selected string value from the picker in previous view**];
```

Please identify the change I am trying to do,i.e. Grp = '%@'-The string is selected value from row component in picker view which is in previous view.

I am aware of 2 possible ways for getting access,

```
1.subclassing the view controller i.e. 

@interface viewController2:viewController1,but I already have subclassed i.e.:

@interface viewController2:addReminderController ,so I cant subclass twice,I am not aware too!

2. Creating an instance object of the viewController1 i.e.
```

`viewController1 *vC1 and I tried to access the groupPicker like [vC1.groupPicker selectedRowInComponent:row],`

but as we can expect it throws an error i.e. **row undeclared** ,

I tried to access the array as I have assigned for number of rows in component for groupPicker as [self.groupArray count],so I tried to make the tactic work in viewController2 too i.e.:

```
[vC1.groupArray objectAtIndex:row],as expected the same error: **row undeclared**
```

So how can I get access to row(string) selected in picker view which is present in previous view,so that I can exhibit good programming habit which is a good sign in future for a fresher like me :)

Please help me with some valuable suggestions

Thanks all in advance :)

Comment: Are you looking to get selected value fron Pickerview and That string to be used in next view?

Comment: @KAREEMMAHAMMED Yeah exactly,any suggestions please.Thanks for the concern :)

Comment: @EshwarChaitanya : why don't you use appDelegate for your application?

Comment: @iCoder86 I already have appDelegate for my app,please suggest me what to do now,thanks for the comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Take a NSString variable in your appDelegate.

Step 2: create instance of appDelegate in your both view were your want to set value and get value as following.

```
yourApplicationDelegate *appDelegate;
```

Step 3: init appDelgate in implementation file as following

```
appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

after this statement you can use the string variable from both view controller you declared in appDelegate of you application.

That's it. now you can assign value from first view and access it in second view.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare NSString in Secondview globally and it is better to take a button and in that action You have to write

Take a NSString *selectedString  globally in firest view
in Pickerview delegate method

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
   selectedString=    [arrayNo objectAtIndex:row];

//here array is the array used for pickerview 
}

-(IBAction)btnAction:(id)sender
{
SecondView *sec=[[SecondView alloc]initWithNibname:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
sec.stringFromPrevView=selectedString;
[self presentModalViewController:sec animated:YES];
[sec release];
}
```

stringFromPrevView this string will be use in Your SecondView as per Your requirement

I hope this will helps You

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer will implement and get back to you :)

Comment: I have a button in view1 when I click the button picker view appears,then when the user selects the row,it navigates to view controller 2 with table view displaying reminders corresponding to row selected from picker view in previous view.

I did what all you suggested i.e. selectedString= [arrayNo objectAtIndex:row]; and assigned it to string view controller2,i.e. sec.stringFromPrevView=selectedString;
I displayed it in console,NSLog(@"String = %@",sec.stringFromPrevView].Working correct

Comment: but when I use this query in View2 where we display data i.e. ["SELECT * FROM reminders WHERE Grp = =\"%@\"",Group];Group value is getting displayed as null value.Hence the query is not working!How can I assign or reference the string value that we have assigned before navigation to the query,please help me,thanks in advance :)

Comment: KAREEM MAHAMMED waiting for your reply,please help me,thank you :)

Comment: How are you using stringFromPrevView value in Yours secondView . Are you assigning to it Group string

Comment: Yeah,this is the query ["SELECT * FROM reminders WHERE Grp = =\"%@\"",Group];where Group is the string I took in view controller 2,in view controller 2 before navigation,I used the following statement as you suggested : strPrintRepeat = [self.groupArray objectAtIndex:row];
                friendsReminders.Group = strPrintRepeat;
                NSLog(@"Group = %@",friendsReminders.Group);

where strPrintRepeat is the string used in view controller1,thanks :)

Comment: KAREEM MAHAMMMED Sorry for the interruption again,any other alternative/suggestion please,thanks for the patience :)

Comment: The above answer worked for Mr.Kareem,thanks once again for everything :)

Comment: I mean the answer above yours worked please see the check mark for the answer,anyway I am up voting because the logic is correct,but the strategy is not regarding my requirement.But it works for some other task,thanks :)

Comment: No I am from guntur,but currently in hyderabad