# Why is an error occurring when a UITableView row is deleted?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am trying to implement a standard delete of a UITableViewCell using the standard edit control style as described in the Apple Table View Programming Guide. When the following code executes in the commitEditingStyle method

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

I get the following error message

*Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 2.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's the only row, I suggest you delete the section as well. You also need to sync your data source with your table, i.e. delete the row in your data source as well.

Here's a correct example when the file system is your data source in iOS:

```
 // Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    // Delete the row from the data source.
        File *file = (File *)[self.files objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:file.path error:nil];
        [self.files removeObject:file];
        if (indexPath.row == 0 && [self.files count] == 0) {
            NSInteger sectionIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition:0];
            [tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }else {
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }
        [self setupData];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
    // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }   
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with an empty section. The problem here as pointed out by Tom Irving is solely updating the data model to fit the removed item.

Comment: The clean and proper way to handle removing the last row is to delete the section. My answer is the most complete and helpful to the OP. There's many great examples of this, including my own experience developing. Here's a StackOverflow demonstrating one case (18 upvotes):
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1265050/230571

Comment: Whether you want to keep empty sections or delete the sections entirely is a matter of preference. If that's what's required (either by the dev or the client) then that's how you do it, I don't care how many upvotes.

Comment: The method I demonstrated covers most cases—which was intended because the OP doesn't yet understand how this part of the SDK works. Of course it's not about the upvotes, it's about what they represent—that it worked for a lot of developers that didn't know how to handle the situation beforehand.

Comment: "If it's the only row, you need to delete the section as well", my point was you don't *need* to, but it is often done.

Comment: If the last row in a section is deleted by the user and you then want to display a row "No data exists" in place of that row, how would you approach that implementation?

Comment: @ChrisP you can have a conditional statement in cellForRowAtIndexPath, numberOfRowsInSection etc. that checks to see if the data source is empty and issues a single cell based on that. You'd return 1 in numberOfRowsInSection and create the cell with "No data exists" in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 4):

You have to remove the object the cell is representing from your data source as well as removing the cell:

```
[myObjectsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```