# dynamically add cells to a grouped uitableview and fit the scroll programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to create programmatically a uitableview that can scroll and fit based on the number of cells, so if i am adding more cells, i could scroll up and down without the page bouncing.

I tried to do this but it doesnt work:

```
tblSimpleTable = [[UITableView alloc]  initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 640) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped ];
tblSimpleTable.scrollEnabled = YES;
tblSimpleTable.dataSource = self;
tblSimpleTable.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:tblSimpleTable];
```

when i add more cells, i can scroll up and down, but the page bounces up so i can't click on the bottom cells. I want to be able to scroll and "stay" where i stop.

UPDATE: just to clarify, since I am using a Grouped table, i dont want to show empty cells, and so i am not sure what should be the height of the able since i may have 1 cell or 100 of them.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061071/uitableview-deleting-sections-with-animation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you aren't staying where you stop is because your UITableView's height is 640. This means that when you completely scroll all the way down in your UITableView some of the cells will be below the bounds of the view you are looking through. You have two options: decrease your table view height, or add some dummy cells to the bottom of your table view.

Comment: thats exactly my problem - to size should i set the height? i may have only one cell or 100 cells, and since its "Grouped" i dont want to show empty cells.

Comment: The table view is actually a custom scroll view created by apple. So it doesn't really matter if the tableView is 20 or 1000 in height it will handle placing the cells in the appropriate way. I would say set the height to be the height of your view. CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you don't want your tableview scroll to bounce, you could set the "bounces" property of the tableview to NO.

```
tableView.bounces = NO;
```